# BeginForm do ASP.NET não aplica o mapeamento de rota ao efetuar a requisição

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou com um problema de rota(novamente), utilizo o ASP.NET MVC5, e tenho a seguinte rota mapeada:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Search_route",
    "Home/Search/{search_input}/{search_input_category}",
    new { 
        controller = "Home",
        action = "Search",
        search_input = UrlParameter.Optional,
        search_input_category = UrlParameter.Optional
    }

);
```

Se eu aplicar: `Url.Action("Search", "Home", new { search_input = "casa", search_input_category = "vetores" })` o meu retorno será: **/Home/Search/casa/vetores**. Porém ao tentar utilizar essa rota no seguinte form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "search-form" })){
         //Todos os campos de input devidamente nomeados
}
```

Quando faço a requisição a minha url retorna **/Home/Search?search_input=Casa&search_input_category=vetores** Ou seja, a rota está correta, porém não está sendo aplicada no `<form>` por algum motivo. É possível aplicar a rota ao formulário de alguma maneira?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema aí é que o sistemas de rotas escolhe a primeira rota compatível para construir a rota e não a personalizada.

Para especificar uma rota personalizada, utilize o método [`Html.BeginRouteForm()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd505047(v=vs.118).aspx). Nele você passa o nome da rota que você criou, no caso é `Search_route`.

**Exemplo:**

```
@using (Html.BeginRouteForm("Search_route", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "search-form" }))
```